# How to alter the mount point of PostgreSQL through Docker?

Tags: postgresql, docker

I want to spin-up a docker for `postgres:latest` but let the data be stored on the host. This is how I do it right now but doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
docker run --name name1 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PASSWORD1 -e POSTGRES_USER=USER1 -e PGDATA=/my/local/path/postgresql -e POSTGRES_DB=DB1 -d -P postgres:latest
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to [mount the host directory as a data volume first](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume) with `-v host_path:contiainer_path:mode`.

```sh
docker run \
  --name name1 \
  -v /my/local/path/postgresql:/data \
  -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PASSWORD1 \
  -e POSTGRES_USER=USER1 \
  -e PGDATA=/data \
  -e POSTGRES_DB=DB1 \
  -d -P postgres:latest
```

The path should exist in the container image.

Comment: thanks for your answer but why are you using `/data` instead of `/var/lib/postgresql/data` ? apparently, the official container utilises the latter one... Am I right, or I don't get it?

Comment: in addition, as far as I can see, the newly created directory `/my/local/path/postgresql` grants permissions on user `999` and group `root` and hence I cannot see the contents of that directory under my very own user name. Is that normal? How can I migrate the data on a different machine later on if I am unable to access that directory?

Comment: The path inside the container is arbitrary, using `/var/lib/postgresql/data` is fine. You would need a user with a matching UID in the container to the owner of the data on the host.

Comment: hello again. regarding the `UID`, and given that my `user id` (in the host machine) is `1000` and `1000` respectively, does it mean that I have to download the Docker file, set both `999` to `1000`, and finally, build (and run) the container?